# Business hours for specific Dates in full calendar

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using fullcalendar to let users book an appointment with clients at specific availability set by the clients. So have to disable the fullcalendar when the client is not available. Currently I am able to set multiple business hours for whole calendar i.e. all the years and months.

But I am not able set for specific chunks of date ranges. I need to set different business hours for different date ranges in full calendar. For example from 5th Jan 2016 to 25th Jan 2016 i want to set business hours 08:00 AM to 06:00 PM after that date I want to set business hours 09:00 AM to 08:00 PM for 1st Feb to 15th Feb. Remaining Date should be disabled for creating event for whole year and above specified date and time should be enabled to create event.
I tried many options but it seems there aren't enough options to fulfill my requirement. So calling for some help if someone can.

Comment: Hai Sanchit , I am also working on same requirement.Have you got any solution?If Yes,Please let me know. Tnx